# ffmpeg x264 CPU core scaling

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264

Does anyone have any experence with this type of thing? Currently using a Ryzen 7 8c/16T CPU, and using a program called [BES](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/). Using 10% CPU, is almost no slower at transcoding from mkv to mp4 (both x264, i know i can just copy them) than using 100% cpu on all 16 threads. So, Since this is the case, What is the ideal core count for libx264? I mean, Does the same type of thing happen with 32 threads? Or 8 threads, etc.

Comment: if it is just repackaging h.264 from  mkv to mp4 it is probably not using x264 or libx264... I am not familiar with whatever program that is... but in ffmpeg you can test a trans code , and a copy separately on the cli with `-c copy` to copy the streams...

Comment: The program allows you to adjust the amount of cpu cycles given to any program, which allows for an adjusted cpu usage, so if i want to encode and use the web at the same time, i could allow ffmpeg to use only 90% cpu, anyways, -c:v libx264 should be using it correct?

Comment: yeah, that should be decoding the audio and encoding with x264... which depending on the preset, level, resolution, etc... can be slower or faster than real time

Answer (score 0):

The core count is a matter of personal taste. Whether you value speed more over quality.

Short answer: 
Fewer threads = higher quality per bit
More threads = higher encoding speed

Long answer:
many x264 encoders compresses well when it can look ahead to what other frames are coming, so the further it can read forward, the better. But multi threading chops the workload into a bundle of frames for each thread/core. It can't look ahead too far that way, inserting a keyframe each time a thread picks up a new bundle and therefore increasing the bandwidth or decreasing quality. More cores, more keyframes.

So, if you want quality, you encode with just one thread. However, you can instead start multiple threads for different videos.

If you want speed, by all means, use all the cores you have available.

Comment: "The quality loss from multiple threads is mostly negligible unless using very high numbers of threads (say, above 16)." From [MeGUI/x264 Settings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MeGUI/x264_Settings#threads), which basically concurs from similar statements I've seen made by x264 developers. So just let x264 choose the optimal number threads automatically.